# Questions on Delphi function parameters

Tags: delphi

I'm a C programmer came across this Delphi function and have a few questions.

```
procedure Init(const key; size: Integer; filler: Byte = $FF); overload
```

1. variable `key` doesn't have a type specified, what is the type of it in this case?
2. What does the "`$FF`" means for the variable `filler`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Key` parameter is an *untyped parameter*. You can found more info in this great article from [Rob Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy), [`What is an untyped parameter?`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/untyped)

The `$FF` value (0xFF hex, 255 decimal) for the filler parameter is a *default value*, so if you do not assign a value to this parameter, the filler will take the default value.

When you call the init procedure you can call in these two ways:

```
Init(Data,1,19);//in this case the key parameter is set to 19
```

or

```
Init(Data,1); //in this case the key parameter is set to $FF
```

Comment: The example calls to Init are missing the size parameter, which is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

$FF is default value for variable filler, key is an constant value of any type. It maybe integer or int64 type